# Contour TIN Interpolation

Tags: qgis, interpolation, contour, terrain

I'm attempting to interpolate the NU national grid square of Ordnance Survey's terrain data (10m intervals). If I interpolate with IDW, I encounter no issues and the raster pixels are square in shape as they should be. When interpolating with TIN (much better for conducting viewsheds over) the NU national grid square returns non-square pixels after the interpolation process. When using the viewshed plugin this creates obscure viewshed as shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240222/viewshed-plugin-gives-incorrect-results/240231#240231). Can anybody else confirm you receive non-square pixels?

When trying to fix this, I was given an error "wkb access out of bounds".

This error has been appearing more and more ever since I first encountered it to the point where its occurring consistently with every TIN interpolation. I have tried the following:

restarting QGIS and the computer

different national grid squares

meticulously gone over CRS selections

checked the validity of the contours

clipped the contours to smaller areas

downgraded my version of QGIS - all at no avail.

I'm using QGIS 2.18.10. I'm conducting the TIN interpolation by navigating to `Raster > interpolate` and using the viewshed plugin (or would have been if the interpolation worked).

Comment: Could you elaborate how you have created the contours? Does it keep the original extent (or partial)?

Comment: They were downloaded from Ordnance Survey. The contours download in national grid squares for the UK, each square sub sequentially being split by a further approximately 10 squares so they must be merged together to form a single national grid square. Not sure what you mean, original extent or partial extent.

Comment: TIN interpolation gives excellent output but it is hard to work with (just in general sense), especially when we have unmatching bounding box / extent in our dataset. If v.clean does not help to solve the issue, consider idw. Or you may find r.surf.contour (after rasterize) is preferable option.

Comment: I just don't uinderstand why QGIS is giving me this error now when in the past it's worked just fine, even with the same dataset and interpolation method.

Comment: Adding your workflow(s) to your post with focus on differences  between previous and current (if any), is appreciated.

Comment: could it [be related to this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/240231/55203)? The viewshed plugin doesn't handle non-square cells (but if you're using OS data, that shouldn't be a problem, unless there's some projection weirdness going on). Can you update your question with the  exact definition of 27700 of your rasters and contour layers?

Comment: @StevenKay! Thank you for dropping in. As you helped me discover the answer to the "non-square cells post", you would find it strange that when I interpolate the NU national grid square of OS terrain data, the raster contains non-square pixels. As you may know, the NU grid square is made up of approximately 10 or 12 smaller grids. If I interpolate one of the smaller grids the interpolation works. I fear it has something to do with merging the NU national grid square. No matter how many times I try the merge, the interpolation still gives me grieve. Out of interest, do you find the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was importing my contour data from a spatiaLite database. If I used the raw files I imported into the database instead, the error was no longer appearing. If I clip the contours, the error will re-appear - this does not appear to be an issue as the interpolation plugin manages just fine despite working off large contours data sets.